# Clicking on ContentControl does not give it focus

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm using my own class, derived from a ContentControl (let's call it MyControl) I want the user to be able to subscribe to the KeyDown and KeyUp events for my control.

The problem I'm having is that MyControl doesn't seem to receive any key events. I've deduced that this is likely an issue of focus. For example, if I add a button to my project that programmatically  sets the focus on MyControl then I will start receiving these events. The problem is that as soon as I click anywhere, including on my own control, it seems to lose focus (either way, the keys aren't working anymore). I can't get it back by clicking either, but it seems that I have to use the MyControl.Focus method.

So, my question is: How do I make the control able to accept focus by clicking on it?

---

Also, included for your enjoyment, I've added a small sample project below to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Focus.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Focus"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="BG">

    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
            <Button Content="Focus" Click="FocusClick"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="InfoText" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Focus
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public static MainPage Current;
    public MyControl ctrl;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
        ctrl = new MyControl();
        BG.Children.Add(ctrl);

        ctrl.KeyDown += ctrl_KeyDown;
        ctrl.KeyUp += ctrl_KeyUp;
    }

    void ctrl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowInfo("Pressed " + e.Key);
    }

    private void ctrl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowInfo("Released " + e.Key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void ShowInfo(string text)
    {
        InfoText.Text = text + Environment.NewLine + InfoText.Text;
    }

    private void FocusClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ctrl.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
}
}
```

MyControl.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace Focus
{
public class MyControl : ContentControl
{

    public MyControl()
        : base()
    {
        LinearGradientBrush lb = new LinearGradientBrush();
        lb.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        lb.EndPoint = new Point(1, 1);
        lb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Colors.Red, Offset = 0, });
        lb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Colors.Yellow, Offset = 1, });

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 800;
        rect.Height = 1000;
        rect.Fill = lb;
        this.Content = rect;
    }
}
}
```

This is done with a blank project called Focus.
The 3 files above are MainPage.xaml, MainPage.xaml.cs, and MyControl.cs, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your example and seems like there is some bug in WinRT, you can read this [MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/5ce24f74-00dc-471c-8a2b-a221423df1b0/). As a workaround you can add subscription to `LostFocus` event of your control:

```
ctrl.LostFocus += ctrl_LostFocus;
void ctrl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyControl)sender).Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

and set focus to your control manually every time when it lost.
But as for me it's bad solution, because your control will be always focused. Of course you can extend this method to provide some additional logic.

Comment: What I've found since is that if I let me control subscribe to the PointerReleased event and then programmatically set the focus to the control it will work, provided I set e.Handled to true.

Without e.Handled it doesn't work. I assume this is because there's a parent Frame element (default, even a parent of MainPage) that will take the focus if it gets the event with e.handled = false.

Comment: Yes, but if you set e.Handled to true any control that lays in visual tree above your control will not receive PointerReleased event, so you must have this in mind.

Comment: Yes. Still, it seems to be the way it works in Windows 8. For example, if you have a ScrollViewer and set it's IsTabStop to true, it will handle PointerReleased events (which it doesn't otherwise).